# setting one line item 'active' at a time in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a small unordered list in a vue template:

```
<ul style="border-bottom:none !important; text-decoration:none">
     <li class="commentToggle" v-bind:class="{active:commentActive}" v-on:click="setInputName('new')">New Comment</li>
     <li class="commentToggle" v-bind:class="{active:commentActive}" v-on:click="setInputName('note')">Note</li>
</ul>
```

and I then have a data variable for commentActive and a function I call to set the input name:

```
data () {
    return {
        commentActive: false,
    }
},
methods: {
   setInputName(str) {
     this.inputName = str;
     this.commentActive = true;
   },

}
```

And this is functional but it is obviously setting BOTH inputs to active when I click on one of them. How do I alter this to only set the clicked line item active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a unique identifier to determine which comment is active. In the most rudimentary way using your current setup:

```
<li class="commentToggle" 
        v-bind:class="{active:commentActive === 'new'}" 
        v-on:click="setInputName('new')">
    New Comment
</li>
<li class="commentToggle" 
        v-bind:class="{active:commentActive === 'note'}" 
        v-on:click="setInputName('note')">
    Note
</li>
```

```
setInputName(str) {
  this.inputName = str;
  this.commentActive = str;
},
```

The adjustment that we made is to ensure that the `commentActive` matches the `str` that we've used. You can change that identifier to anything else, and pass additional arguments if you so choose.

Comment: of course, that makes sense now. I appreciate it, I think sometimes I try to overcomplicate with vue. Thanks!